# I need to pass the html tag in to the variable, and it should display html element

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

I need to input element in the table header, headers are passed from ts file. I stored the tag from string and stored in the variable and padding to header and its showing [HTMLInputElemnt] in the header.

I need inputs in that place, How to achieve it??
Thanks In advance.

Declaraion:

```
export interface Custom {
  title?: string;
  field?: string;
  default?: 0;
  type?: string;
}
```

TypeScript Functions

```
     ngOnInit() {
    this.inputHead = this.htmlToElement('<input value="3">');
    console.log(this.inputHead,"op")

    this._config = {
      name: "Custom",
      properties: this._tableHeader
    };


    this._tableHeader = [
      { title: 'Test Name', field: 'testname', type: 'text', default: 0 },
      { title: 'Initial', field: 'initial', type: 'any', default: 0 },
      { title: this.inputHead, field: 'check', type: 'any', default: 0 },
      { title: this.inputHead, field: 'check', type: 'any', default: 0 }
    ];


    this.testData = [
      { testname: 'Color Test' },
      { testname: 'Humidity Test' },
      { testname: 'Weight Test' },
      { testname: 'Composition Test' },
    ]
    this.cdRef.markForCheck();
  }
   htmlToElement(html:any) {
    var template = document.createElement('template');
    html = html.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
    template.innerHTML = html;
    console.log(template.content.firstChild ,);
    return template.content.firstChild;   
}
}
```

Output
[image: Output i am getting]

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frh5eh @Rajat I am not showing what im using coz im using other components also, but result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but you could just return `template` instead of `template.content.firstChild` and then use property binding instead of string interpolation as follows:

```
<div [innerHTML]="inputHead.innerHTML | sanitizeHtml"></div>
```

The method `htmlToElement` returns an object of type `HTMLTemplateElement` and you need to bind to its `innerHTML` property. Also, sanitize the value as Angular recognizes it as an unsafe value.
Here's the updated Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2v9ro

Comment: in your example, can i pass different increment values from array?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqijrg?file=src/app/app.component.html

in my project im pusing data from another component to array on button click, so for button click it need to genarate inputs. @Rajat

Comment: Yeah, that should be doable. Try using *ngFor

Comment: got it @Rajat TY